# java mysql - how to perform many complex calculations fast?

Tags: java, mysql, bigdata

I have following problem:

I'm searching for similarities. Therefore I have a big source table with 200000 entries and second table with 10000 entries. Now I'm retrieving a entry set for each table and compare every row in the source table with every row in the second table in java (I'm using some NeedleMan Gotoh algorithm and similar more complex algorithms). That means 1 billion comparisons and that's too much and too slow...

The goal is a table with all similarities (id from source table, id from second table and a similarity value) or at least something like the best match (or best x matches) for every entry...

Could anyone give me some advice to do such calculations in a "normal" time?

**EDIT**

Main Table

```
---+------+-------------+---------+-------+
id | name | address     | country | plz   | ...
---+------+-------------+---------+-------+
20 | Sony | Main Str. 1 | US      | 10000 |
---+------+-------------+---------+-------+
```

Second Table

```
---+------+-------------+---------+-------+
id | name | address     | country | plz   | ...
---+------+-------------+---------+-------+
30 | Soni | MainStr. 1  | US      | 10000 |
---+------+-------------+---------+-------+
```

Goal (similarity table):

```
---+---------------+--------------+-----------+
id | id_source_tbl | id_second_tbl| similarity|
---+---------------+--------------+-----------+
1  | 20            | 30           | 0.99      |
---+---------------+--------------+-----------+
```

simil_value is a value that indicates, how likely the company in the source table is the same as the company in the second table

the result indicates, that the two rows are representing the same company... the two entries just differ because of small typos... (0.99 is the similarity and is very high => companies are the same)
Similarity is calculated with a needleman wunsch gotoh algorithm (comparing char for char and considering position in string and so on... typos should result in a high similarity value)

Comment: Please post the structure of your tables

Comment: Can't you have MySQL "precompute" some of the data for you instead of doing everything in Java?

Comment: actually, at first, that's not the problem... 2 billion calculations, even if everyone would be finished in 1ms, would need about 23 days... So first I've to find a way to avoid some of these calculations... I don't have an idea for that yet, though...

Comment: @prom85 We need more information on the calculations. I'd suggest adding some example data sets to your tables in the question, and an exmaple of what the results should look like

Comment: These are quadratic or cubic algorithms anyway as between any two pairs, where N is the length of each string, and you're adding another O(N**2) by comparing 200,000 items to 100,000 other items. So the performance is going to be O(N**4) or O(N**5). You've set yourself a rather infeasible problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I made the problem myself...

Solution for me was following:
1) don't reuse connections, always close them with the corresponing ResultSet
2) use transactions
3) split work to threads
4) if you, like me, have results for single rows (ALL similarities for one single entry) and want to calc something on this subresult (like in my case, for all similarities I wanted to calc the rank), do this in java and use the subresult!!!! instead of doing it afterwards in mysql

The result for me is about 1 day of calculation time instead of 3 weeks...

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an embarrassingly parallel problem, so as a first step, you could do your analyses on multiple cores and machines.

Comment: actually, that's no alternative for me... the hardware for that is not available for me.. Quad-Core is all I have and one machine...

Comment: So, be sure to use all four cores.

Comment: These days, you don't need to actually own the computers.  The cloud can supply you with nearly infinite compute resources for a price.  If you want your job done quickly, grab 1000 amazon instances and go to town.  23 days (your estimate, I think) becomes 30 minutes or so.

Answer (score 1):

It usually makes more sense to allow MySQL to perform data selection rather than to retrieve a massive data set and then use your own algorithms to filter it. It sounds like all you're doing is a fairly simple join operation e.g.:

```
SELECT source_id_column, second_id_column, similarity_column
FROM source_table, second_table
WHERE source_table.similarity_column = second_table.similarity;
```

Comment: the similarity column is not existing... the values have to been calculated first... and afterwards I need the best matches...

Comment: @prom85 Can you be specific? It may still be possible for MySQL to do all that. What is being calculated, and what do you mean by "best matches" - equality? Numbers close in range?

Comment: @prom85 Perhaps post an example data set, and what the results should look like

Comment: @prom85 You've defined the tables, but not an example of the data and what calculations you are performing. It's hard to suggest a solution without knowing that info.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you would express this as:

select t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2,
          calculate_similarity(t1.name, t2.name) as similarity
   from t1 cross join
        t2

Now, you want to define the similarity table as:

```
create table similarity (
    SimilarityID int not null auto_increment,
    id1 int,
    id2 int,
    similarity float
)
```

Then do the insert as:

```
insert into similarity(id1, id2, similarity)
    select t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2,
           calculate_similarity(t1.name, t2.name) as similarity
    from t1 cross join
         t2
```

The SQL engine should do the cross join in parallel as well as the similarity calculation.  Perhaps you have a way to limit the query, such as requiring that the companies be in the same state or start with the same letter.

Comment: that would mean I have to write a sql procedure, doesn't it? I can't use a java function directly in the sql query somehow, do I?